# Three dimensional array function argument c

Tags: c, arrays

I am working on a lab and I need some help!
Lets say I have a 3 dimensional array double a[2][3][4]. I want to update the values of inside this array through void functions. How would I set that up? I am having trouble initializing a pointer to the double that I want send in as an argument. I want to do something to every value inside of the 3d array so all 24 values?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
void MyFunction (double a[2][3][4])
{
  int i,j,k ;

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
      {
        a[i][j][k] = 5.0 ;
      }
}

void main()
{
 double a[2][3][4] ;
 MyFunction(a) ;
 // now every element of array a contains 5.0
}
```

Comment: so just to clarify.. in void MyFunction.. if i set every value of the array to 5 lets say.. after the call MyFunction(a); in main.. every value of a will be 5 correct?

Comment: Yes. Why don't you just try.